# Export plot from plotly into PDF

Tags: r, pdf, plotly

I use package plotly in order to make some plots. And the end my intention is to put this plot with high resolution in pdf. I don't know way but ggplot2 give me permission to do this, but with plotly I can't use option from R-Studio and convert directly into PDF. You can see that on pic below:

[image]

In order to fix this problem I try to do this with this lines of code:

```
 pdf(file=paste("FINAL_plot.pdf",sep=""),width=10, height=5)
          
          op <- par(mgp=c(1,0,0),mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1),# Room for the title and legend: 1_bottom,2_left,3_up,4_right
                    mfrow=c(1,2))
          
          plot(FINAL_plot)

          
          dev.off()
```

But unfortunately this lines of code didn't work and PDF is empty. So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orca is now deprecated. You now must use Kaleido to install. In similarity to Orca, you must first have the Kaleido library installed on your OS.
To install:

```
install.packages('reticulate')
reticulate::install_miniconda()
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido')
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'plotly', channel = 'plotly')
reticulate::use_miniconda('r-reticulate')
```

To export:

```
library(plotly)
kaleido(FINAL_plot, "FINAL_plot.pdf")
```

Comment: For users which got the error message: `sys` is not defined. I had to load the python modul sys via reticulate `reticulate::import("sys")` before you save the image. And in the `plotly` description the function `save_image()` is suggested instead of `kaleido()`

Answer (score 1):

Plotly plots can only be exported using the additional orca command line utility (https://github.com/plotly/orca)

You would first need to install the orca library on your OS (see https://github.com/plotly/orca#installation for details). After that you can export your plot using

```r
library(plotly)
orca(FINAL_plot, "FINAL_plot.pdf")
```

Comment: `orca` is deprecated and has been substitued with `kaleido` instead. It also requires the `reticulate` package.